# Create segues in RealityKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit

I want to add a segue in my Reality Kit project between a simple swiftUI page and the AR camera ContentView. Here is my SegueView, the swiftui page that has a button which I want to segue to the AR view.

```
struct SegueView: View {
    @State private var isActive: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(rootActive: $isActive), isActive: $isActive, label: {
            Text("See in AR")
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the code from my ContentView, which only renders a box:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @Binding var rootActive: Bool
    var body: some View {
        return ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        // Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
        let box = ModelEntity(mesh: MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.3), materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .blue, isMetallic: true)])
        
        anchor.addChild(box)
        // Add the box anchor to the scene
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        
        return arView
        
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {} 
}
```

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0qmeoswVvM) tutorial to create the segue, but it doesn't contain an AR view and I cannot find a tutorial that does. I also have to add the rootActive variable in the app delegate here:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView(rootActive: .constant(true))

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

But since the tutorial doesn't have this step, I'm not entirely sure what to do. When I run the app, only the ContentView gets rendered. Does anyone know how I can create a segue where the SegueView is rendered first, and then when the navigation link "see in AR" is pressed, it goes to the ContentView?

Thanks!

Comment: In your `@main` file (generally named [YourAppName]App, did you change `ContentView()` to `SegueView()`?

Comment: Segue is a term that is used in UIKit. That code you got from the tutorial is terrible. Don’t use that, constant should only be used in previews. Put the main wrapper on the SegueView and you should get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ContentView, put NavigationLink inside NavigationView.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {           
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.black
                
                VStack {    
                    NavigationLink(destination: Reality().ignoresSafeArea()) {
                        Text("Go to ARView")
                            .foregroundColor(.cyan)
                            .font(.title3)
                    }                   
                }
            }.ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

`ARView`

```
struct Reality: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.2))
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
        anchor.addChild(model)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

P. S.

In project's `Info` tab add key `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I'm hoping to create an app to teach kids physics through AR, and I wouldn't be able to do that without this.